Add parameters in Dagster & DLTHub pipeline
I have a problem with addding parameters to Dagster pipeline. I could somehow add parameters, but it doesn't work.
It applies some default ones. Example on image

And there is no data in Config tab in Dagster UI

I have this asset:
from dagster import (
    AssetExecutionContext,
    AutoMaterializePolicy,
    AutoMaterializeRule,
    SourceAsset,
    file_relative_path, asset, AssetKey,
    Config,
    ConfigurableResource
)
from dagster._annotations import public
from typing import Optional
from dagster_embedded_elt.dlt import (
    DagsterDltResource,
    DagsterDltTranslator,
    dlt_assets,
)
from dlt import pipeline

from dlt.extract.resource import DltResource
from dlt_sources.weather_api import weather

dlt_resource = DagsterDltResource()

from dagster_embedded_elt.dlt import DagsterDltTranslator

class CustomDagsterDltTranslator(DagsterDltTranslator):
    def get_deps_asset_keys(self, resource: DltResource):
        # Specify the dependency on the Dagster asset
        return [AssetKey("foo")]


class PipelineConfig(Config):
    pipeline_name: str = ''
    destination: str = 'bigquery'
    dataset_name: str = ''

# @asset(group_name='weather_current_conditions')
# def foo():
#     key = '123'
#     return key

config = PipelineConfig()
@dlt_assets(
    dlt_source=weather(),
    dlt_pipeline=pipeline(
        pipeline_name=config.pipeline_name,
        destination=config.destination,
        dataset_name=config.dataset_name,
    ),
    dlt_dagster_translator=CustomDagsterDltTranslator(),
    name="weather_current_conditions_asset",
    group_name='weather_current_conditions'
)
def weather_assets(context: AssetExecutionContext, dlt: DagsterDltResource):
    # foo_key = context.resources.foo
    # print(context.log.info(foo_key))
    yield from dlt.run(
        context=context
    )


I've read from Dagster Docs that we could use the Config class. I created the simple class PipelineConfig with parameters which @dlt_assets decorator accepts.
I found the video from Dagster Talks about Configuration & Resources where the parameters have been  configured.
In my Definitions class I've added the next run_config in ScheduleDefinition class. But, it doesn't work.
from dagster import Definitions, ScheduleDefinition, define_asset_job, RunConfig

from .assets import dlt_weather
from dagster_embedded_elt.dlt import DagsterDltResource

from .assets.dlt_weather import PipelineConfig

dlt_resource = DagsterDltResource()

defs = Definitions(
    assets=[
        dlt_weather.weather_assets
    ],
    resources={
        "dlt": dlt_resource,
    },
    jobs=[
        define_asset_job(
            name='ingest_current_weather_conditions_to_staging_job',
            selection=[dlt_weather.weather_assets],
        )
    ],
    schedules=[ScheduleDefinition(
        name='weather_current_conditions_schedule',
        job_name='ingest_current_weather_conditions_to_staging_job',
        cron_schedule='@hourly',
        run_config=RunConfig(
            ops={
                "weather_current_conditions_asset": PipelineConfig(
                    pipeline_name='weather_current_conditions_pipeline',
                    destination='bigquery',
                    dataset_name="dlt_stg_weather_data"

                )
            }
        ).to_config_dict()
    )]
)


I expect to have a scheduled config with parameters I can define which  Dagster pipeline could use.
Thanks in advance for your time and help
